# How to add delay in onDraw() in android canvas?

Tags: java, android, canvas, delay, ondraw

I am making a project. It draws concentric circles in android canvas. When the user drags the screen, all the circles move accordingly. Here is my code so far.

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

        <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/scrollableSpace"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

        <project.myProject.DrawOrbit
            android:id="@+id/orbitsRegion"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />


    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnTouchListener
{
    PointF center;
    center.x=500;center.y=500;
    float radius[]={100,200,300,400,500};
    DrawOrbit orbit;
    int startX=0,startY=0,currentX=0,currentY=0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        RelativeLayout layout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.scrollableSpace);
        orbit.draw(center,radius);

        layout.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }   


    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent motionEvent)
    {

        final int action= motionEvent.getAction();
        switch(action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK)
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            {              
                startX=(int)motionEvent.getRawX();
                startY=(int)motionEvent.getRawY();             

                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            {
                currentX=(int)motionEvent.getRawX();
                currentY=(int)motionEvent.getRawY();               

                float diffX=currentX-startX;
                float diffY=currentY-startY;

                startX=currentX;
                startY=currentY;

                center.x+=diffX;
                center.y+=diffY;
                orbit.draw(center,radius);

                break;
            }          

        }
        return true;

    }
}
```

DrawOrbit.java

```
public class DrawOrbit extends View
{
    PointF center;
    float radius[];
    public DrawOrbit(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public DrawOrbit(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public DrawOrbit(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        int len=radius.length;
        for(int a=0;a<len;a++)
        {
            canvas.drawCircle(center.x,center.y,radius[a],paint);
        }
    }   

    public void draw(PointF center, float radius[])
    {
        this.center=center;
        this.radius=radius;
        invalidate();        
        requestLayout();
    }
}
```

What I want to do is that the circles should appear one by one. First the inner most circle then the next one after some delay then the next and so on. The same effect should be seen when the screen is dragged. How can I achieve this? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the answer to my own question. I had to use a Handler, multiplied the delay with the for-loop variable and made 1 then 2 then so on.. circles to get the desired effect. Here is the code.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnTouchListener
{
    PointF center;
    center.x=500;center.y=500;
    float radius[]={100,200,300,400,500};
    DrawOrbit orbit;
    int startX=0,startY=0,currentX=0,currentY=0;
    Handler handler1 = new Handler();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        RelativeLayout layout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.scrollableSpace);
        for (int a = 0; a<radius.length ;a++)
        {
            final int index=a;
            handler1.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    orbit.draw(center,radius,index);
                }
            }, 300 * a);
        }

        layout.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }   


    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent motionEvent)
    {

        final int action= motionEvent.getAction();
        switch(action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK)
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            {              
                startX=(int)motionEvent.getRawX();
                startY=(int)motionEvent.getRawY();             

                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            {
                currentX=(int)motionEvent.getRawX();
                currentY=(int)motionEvent.getRawY();               

                float diffX=currentX-startX;
                float diffY=currentY-startY;

                startX=currentX;
                startY=currentY;

                center.x+=diffX;
                center.y+=diffY;

                break;
            } 
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            {
                for (int a = 0; a<radius.length ;a++)
                {
                    final int index=a;
                    handler1.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            orbit.draw(center,radius,index);
                        }
                    }, 300 * a);
                }
                break;
            }

        }
        return true;

    }
}
```

DrawOrbit.java

```
public class DrawOrbit extends View
{
    PointF center;
    float radius[];
    int index;
    public DrawOrbit(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public DrawOrbit(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public DrawOrbit(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        int len=radius.length;
        for(int a=0;a<index;a++)
        {
            canvas.drawCircle(center.x,center.y,radius[a],paint);
        }
    }   

    public void draw(PointF center, float radius[],int index)
    {
        this.center=center;
        this.radius=radius;
        this.index=index;
        invalidate();        
        requestLayout();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a timeout. I'd suggest creating a new thread to draw everything, and start by drawing the first circle, have the method look like this:

```
public void drawCircle() {
    //Draw logic
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
    drawNextCircle();
}
//Assuming on java 1.8+
Thread thread = new Thread() => {
    drawCircle();
}
```

What this will do is have the thread sleep for 3 seconds, and then continue normal operation after the time period is up. You can change it to other measurements of time such as `TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS` or `TimeUnit.MINUTES` as well.

edit: You likely won't want this in your main thread, as it will stop the ENTIRE application from working for however long you put the thread on timeout, so it's almost essential for this to work that you put it in a separate thread.

edit 2: It would make more sense to add a separate util method to timeout and then call another method via reflection than the above code, but the same code would be needed.

Comment: Can you please give a bit of detailed code. I am quite new to this. Thankyou